# Send datagram from gray ip to white ip

Tags: udp, ip

I have two computers, the first computer receives interenet via Ethernet and gives wi-fi to the second computer. First computer have etho(not 192.168.x.x) and wlan0(192.168.150.1). Second computer have wlan0(192.168.150.5). I run a simple chat, and have a situation
2 Computer: message sent from 192.168.150.5 to 192.168.150.1
1 Computer: message received from 192.168.150.5
1 Computer: Message recovering back to 192.168.150.1
Of course message is not received on the second computer. As I understand it sends through eth0 and the message is not delivered. How can I fix this situation?

Comment: Um, what?  This question is very poorly phrased.

Answer (score 0):

So, your situation is you have two computers. One computer is connected to the internet via Ethernet while supplying internet via WiFi adhoc network to your second computer, correct?

```
-Computer A: 192.168.1.2 (example - Ethernet machine)
-Computer B: 192.168.1.3 (example - adhoc WiFi machine)
```

You want to be able to send traffic between the two, correct?

```
-Computer B: Sends message to Computer A
-Computer A: Receives message from Computer B
-Computer A: Echoes(or replies) the message back to Computer B
```

Is this what you're trying to accomplish? What medium are you trying to use? PuTTY? Hyper Term? Your own program? Your WiFi adhoc network should not be the same IP range as your Ethernet network unless you made it so when you made a static IP for the adhoc. Make sure that your medium is talking to the right IP and that there are no conflicts with those IPs...

**In summary:** What operating systems are you using? What applications are you using? Are you sure your Ethernet and adhoc IPs aren't causing collisions between each other?

Comment: I use linux mint and kubuntu. My application is a simple UDP chat from example QT. Ip is static. "Make sure that your medium is talking to the right IP and that there are no conflicts with those IPs" - can you explain this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with QT so I can't offer much guidance in that aspect. In your UDP application, somewhere within the clients code(Computer B), there should be an area where it seeks out a connection to an IP address where the server is located(IP for Computer A) and the port number that the server on Computer A is listening to. Make sure that your application is looking for the correct IP address within your adhoc network and the port number and that none of the machines in the system have the same static IP as anything else on either network(IP conflicts).